# A download manager for Linux which saves downloaded files in directories by date like 2012_06_29

Tags: linux, file-management, download-manager, date

I've been using [Download Master](http://westbyte.com/dm/) on Windows for years and what I liked most about it is that this program can automatically put downloaded files into directories by download date:

```
  /Downloads
  |
  |--/2012_06_28
  |  |
  |  |--a.zip
  |  |--b.pdf
  | ...
  |
  |--/2012_06_29
  |  |
  |  |--c.txt
  | ...
 ...
```

I'm looking for something similar for Linux. Is there any free download manager that can do this?

I have tried [KGet](http://www.kde.org/applications/internet/kget/) and [uGet](http://urlget.sourceforge.net/?page_id=8) but they both seem to lack this feature. If there is a way to configure them to do that, I'll be happy to know about it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

JDownloader 2 (still in Beta) supports exactly that (and much more).

Give it a try [JDownloader 2 - Beta](http://board.jdownloader.org/forumdisplay.php?f=50).

Comment: +1 But can you give more details how to do this? I looked into the Jdownloader 2 beta settings and (beside in the archive extractor plugin) I didn't find a valid way to insert %date% or some similar placeholders. Do you have a link which explains which placeholders are allowed?

Comment: It's just above the archive extractor plugin. See that (german speaking...) [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hbNAQnNs49k). At least to see where it is. It's quite easy to understand when you're in. Just right click an entry (eg filename or folder) and you'll see an entry with placeholders (eg <jd:simpledate:yy.MM.dd_hh>/<jd:packagename>)

Answer (score 1):

You can wite a script using `wget` to achieve this.
Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
DATE=`date +"%Y_%m_%d"`
URL=$1

mkdir -p ~/Downloads/$DATE
cd ~/Downloads/$DATE
wget $URL
```

Name it `downloader.sh`, make it executable and run with `./downloader.sh <URL>`